# how to combine and order a few jquery and datatables features?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I copy-pasted / recreated from tutorials a few features to jquery datatables and got them to work by themselves but I have no idea how to combine them to work.
Simple copy-pasting of them into google will most probably show you where I got them from in case you're wondering or want to point me back to tutorial. Besides not working it gawks

```
"DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3" .
```

I tried just putting them all after `"$(document).ready(function()"` ,
and I think it removes that error but doesn't work as intended;

Here's a jsfiddle (comment if link doesn't work)
https://jsfiddle.net/tqcu4ypL/

```
    <table id="table_id">
    
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Supply</th>
            <th scope="col">Used by</th>
            <th scope="col">Periodicity</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Units</th>
            <th scope="col">Price per unit</th>
            <th scope="col">Price together</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>water</td>
            <td> 
              <span>plant1</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4><b> monthly </b></h4>
            </td>
            <td class="units">
              10
            </td>
            <td> <h4> liters </h4> </td>
            <td class="price">
              2.99
            </td>
            <td class="price_row_total"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>hay</td>
            <td> 
              <span>animal1</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4><b> one time </b></h4>
            </td>
            <td class="units">
              15
            </td>
            <td> <h4> stacks </h4> </td>
            <td class="price">
              1.50
            </td>
            <td class="price_row_total"></td>
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>
    
    </table>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.0/b-1.5.2/b-colvis-1.5.2/b-flash-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/cr-1.5.0/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.0/b-1.5.2/b-colvis-1.5.2/b-flash-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/cr-1.5.0/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
// adds option to copy and download in multiple formats
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable({

    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: {
        name: 'primary',
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]

        }}
    );
} );


// adds fixed footer total that changes depending on filtering.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {

        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

            var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 6 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 6, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );

//adds row grouping by "periodicity" ; supposed to add it as a row separator and remove it as a column
$(document).ready(function() {
    var groupColumn = 2;
    var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": groupColumn }
        ],
        "order": [[ groupColumn, 'asc' ]],
        "displayLength": 25,
        "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null;
 
            api.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="6">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                    );
 
                    last = group;
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
 
    // Order by the grouping
    $('#table_id tbody').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
        var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
        if ( currentOrder[0] === groupColumn && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
            table.order( [ groupColumn, 'desc' ] ).draw();
        }
        else {
            table.order( [ groupColumn, 'asc' ] ).draw();
        }
    } );
} );


//calculates price X units
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
      // this was modified to get price and unit based off class name (changed from subjects)
      const unit = Number($(this).find('.units').text());
      const price = Number($(this).find('.price').text());
      // the toFixed(2) rounds to 2 decimal places as these are floating point numbers you will end up with something like 29.90000002
      const price_row_total = (unit * price).toFixed(2);
      $(this).find('.price_row_total').html(price_row_total);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to combine the different DataTables initialization options, but doing so in separate calls to:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({ /* ... */ });
```

The error is simply telling you that you can't re-initialize the DataTable (can't re-call `.DataTable()` on the same element) after it's already been initialized.  (Side note, there is a method to [*destroy*](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) (de-initialize) a `DataTable` which would then allow it, but that's probably not what you want here.)

The thing to take note of here is what you're passing to the `.DataTable()` function.  It's an object, where each property is a different initialization option.  For example:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
  dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
  buttons: {
    name: 'primary',
    buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
  }
});
```

In that case the object has two properties, `dom` and `buttons`.  So in your case you can simply combine all of those properties into one object and pass that one object to `.DataTable()`:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
  footerCallback: function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
    // Your function...
  },
  columnDefs: [
    { "visible": false, "targets": groupColumn }
  ],
  order: [[ groupColumn, 'asc' ]],
  displayLength: 25,
  drawCallback: function ( settings ) {
    // Your function...
  },
  dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
  buttons: {
    name: 'primary',
    buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
  }
});
```

(Function contents removed for brevity/clarity.)

Two things to note would be:

1. If you have any repeated properties (you don't here, but could as you copy/paste from other tutorials/examples) then you'll need to define how you want to merge the functionality being defined in those properties.  Re-defining a property would (I *think*) only use the one defined last.
2. This code makes no guarantee that there's nothing *else* wrong with your DataTable initialization or implementation.  This is simply addressing the error of trying to re-initialize the same table.

Comment: thank you. This explains the details of how to combine better
@Sven.hig it did the thing ! Thank you ! 
1) both you and Sven.hig answered at about the same time and both answers work, so I'm a bit lost about which one to mark as "solved it", but I'm marking yours even though he provided full jsfiddle showing/fixing all the combination probkems; Lmk if you think otherwise makes more sense. 
2) could you give me a hint about why the question could've been downvoted ? anything about the phrasing ?

Answer (score 1):

It means you can't initialise datatables more than once per table and in your code you are initialising the same table 3 times, to fix the error you have to combine all your filters and setups inside one initialisation

Comment: I made it obvious that I understand this, the question was about how How to do that.

Comment: from what I have read in your question you said you put them all in `$(document).ready(function()` but datatables is initiated using `$('#table_id').DataTable..` so you have to put them all inside that function

Comment: it is the fact that you are using multiple `$('#table_id').DataTable()` that initiates the error

Comment: Yes, and it solved the "Cannot reinitialise" but it did not make them work. Maybe I did something wrong, but if it is as simple as cut-pasting a few times, maybe you have a minuute to show me?

Comment: here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/kdrj9o8w/)

Comment: this seems to put a few of them together but has issues:
1) no fixed footer total that changes depending on filtering.
2) cannot filter grouped rows by clicking on them 
3) sorting is broken (at least on supply_names when I test it on my larger dynamic db)
4) sorting is not working on "price together" at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217156/discussion-between-illevens-and-sven-hig).

Comment: try this code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/9yns6x3o/) and see if it solves the problems if not let me know

Comment: it did the thing ! Thank you ! 
1) both you and David answered at about the same time and both answers work, so I'm a bit lost about which one to mark as "solved it", but I'm marking his as a) he went into detail about combination and b) he answered sooner. Lmk if you think otherwise makes more sense. 
2) could you give me a hint about why the question could've been downvoted ? anything about the phrasing ?